# Django-administration setup

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm trying to set up the django-administration package. I have successfully isntalled it, ran manage.py syncdb and am now trying to set it up.

Under /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/templates/, I have two files base.html and index.html.

I also have /registration/ that contains things like activate.html, logout.html, etc etc...

When I got to /accounts/register, I get:

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/templates/base.html, error at line 15
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is my **base.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}User test{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    {% block header %}
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a> |

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% trans "Logged in" %}: {{ user.username }}
    (<a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'auth_password_change' %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>)
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr />
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="footer">
    {% block footer %}
    <hr />
    {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my **index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
Index page
{% endblock %}
```

I'm new to Django so any help and explanations why this is happening would be much appreciated!

**Edit 1**
Here's urls.py for the main "mysite"

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls',namespace = "polls")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Also, here's the relevant section from **Apache**. Note that I only want to have django respond to a few suburls, that is why I have it like I do:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /polls /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /accounts /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Please, show contents of your urls.py. Django says that it does not know reverse for your index url pattern.
Also, read django docs about url reversing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: There's no need to add the /polls /admin and /accounts URLs to Apache. Just add /, Django will do the rest. You may benefit from going through a tutorial before you proceed  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I did go through the tutorial. The reason I don't have "/" is because I don't want Django to respond to everything. Only very specific suburls....

Comment: I'd would like to see these: `'polls.urls'`,`'registration.backends.default.urls'` but isnt this wrong: `url(r'^', include(admin.site.urls))`. I mean the regular expression, isn't it missing end of line symbol -> $

Comment: it seems to work fine when i type in /admin. In either case, how does that reflect to my index argument issue?

Comment: Can you go to /polls/ ? or /accounts/ ? because I'm gessing `r'^'` will match any url and sendit along to `admin.site.url`, specially if it's first. I think you were looking for `'^$'` (the empty string). Excuse me if I'm writing nonesense, I'm learning Django myself.

Comment: You're right. /admin/polls or /admin/accounts/register always works. /admin/ works always too. However if I do /polls and refresh quickly, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't... not sure why. If you have a better way to set it up, I'd be very glad to hear it.

Comment: I would set `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py` instead of those 3 you have, and change `r'^'`to `r'^admin/'`.

Comment: @vinod, but wouldn't that make Django respond to everything? I don't want it to respond to just <myserverip>

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will have to add every new url prefix you add to your `urls.py` to the apache config as well, since you don't have a common root. You could differentiate  based on vhost however. That way your django site can have a unique hostname that points to the IP address of your server, and Apache can only direct requests to that hostname to your Django server.
If you still want to differentiate between urls at the Apache level, without an index page, then I would change `r'^'` to `r'^admin/'` or move that line to the bottom of your urls list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment you do not want an index/home page:

> The reason I don't have "/" is because I don't want Django to respond to everything. Only very specific suburls....

So why don't you just remove the `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a> |` link? Did you want it to point somewhere else?

Comment: Excellent. Great point. That worked :-). Do you know how to make django respond to https requests? For instance: this works "http://<myip>/admin/accounts/register/" but this does not: "https://<myip>/admin/accounts/register/

Comment: You can reverse proxy via your Apache webserver for that, after terminating SSL there. Don't use the Django development server to expose SSL.